# How to build a library on ROS?

Tags: ros, build, rosmake, ros-indigo, lsd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed lsd_slam and ros-indigo. To use lsd_slam library, I downloaded source code and run `rosmake lsd_slam`.

I try to modify content of this library files. I add below line to 248th line in `main_on_images.cpp under lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/src`. Then I run `rosmake lsd_slam` to build.

```
    printf("getCurrentPoseEstimate\n");
```

I run lsd_slam with dataset using below command :

```
rosrun lsd_slam_core dataset_slam _files:=<files> _hz:=<hz> _calib:=<calibration_file>
```

I don't see `getCurrentPoseEstimate` message. How can I build a library after modifying source code on ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213679/how-to-build-a-library-on-ros?/) by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2015-07-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake is enough. I don't delete this question to help other users.

---

Originally posted by [jossy](https://answers.ros.org/users/20321/jossy/) with karma: 83 on 2015-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0